# Dojo Issue: FilteringSelect , required: "false" , not working

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete, dojo

Dojo : FilteringSelect , required: "false" , not working

**My code structure is,**

```
var user_search = new FilteringSelect({
                        id: "user_search",
                        name: "user_search",
                        searchAttr: "displayName",
                        type: "text",
                        required: "false",
                        autoComplete: true, 
                        labelFunc: formatLabel,
                        labelType: "html",
                        invalidMessage: "No user found",
                        style: "width: 166px;height:28px;background-color:white"
                    }, this.user_search);
```

Can any one help?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should the `required` property be boolean `false`, rather than the string `"false"`?

```
 ...
 type: "text",
 required: false,
 autoComplete: true, 
 ....
```